# How to resolve "sizeof" error while using boost:serialization in c++?

Tags: c++, linux, boost-serialization

I'm using boost::serialization, following is my class and I tried to serialize this class object in the main function.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <map>
#include <sstream>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/access.hpp>
#include <boost/static_assert.hpp>

using namespace boost;
using namespace std;

class gps_position
{
        public:
        int i ;
        int j;
        friend class boost::serialization::access;
        template<class Archive>
        void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version)
        {
                ar & i;
                ar & j;
        }

        gps_position(){};
        gps_position(int a, int b):i(a), j(b){};
};

int main()
{
        std::stringstream ss;
         boost::archive::text_oarchive ar( ss );
         gps_position obj(10, 20);
         ar << obj;
        return 0;
}
```

But I'm getting following compilation errors:

```
/usr/include/boost/archive/detail/oserializer.hpp: In function 'void boost::archive::save(Archive&, T&) [with Archive = boost::archive::text_oarchive, T = gps_position]':
/usr/include/boost/archive/basic_text_oarchive.hpp:78:   instantiated from 'void boost::archive::basic_text_oarchive<Archive>::save_override(T&, int) [with T = gps_position, Archive = boost::archive::text_oarchive]'
/usr/include/boost/archive/detail/interface_oarchive.hpp:78:   instantiated from 'Archive& boost::archive::detail::interface_oarchive<Archive>::operator<<(T&) [with T = gps_position, Archive = boost::archive::text_oarchive]'
client.cpp:70:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/boost/archive/detail/oserializer.hpp:567: error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type 'boost::STATIC_ASSERTION_FAILURE<false>'
```

following are the boost libraries are installed on my system:

```
boost-debuginfo-1.33.1-15.1.el5
boost-debuginfo-1.33.1-15.1.el5
boost-devel-1.33.1-15.1.el5
boost-1.33.1-15.1.el5
boost-1.33.1-15.1.el5
boost-doc-1.33.1-15.1.el5
boost-devel-1.33.1-15.1.el5
```

Any pointer to resolve these compilation errors?

Comment: Guessing here, but you might just need to explicitly include the `<boost/static_assert.hpp>` header?

Comment: Can't [reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1058cf440fe711b0) the error (the errors you see are all linker errors, the code compiles). Can you please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)?

Comment: @Keith I also tried after included above header still errors remain . :(

Comment: @Praetorian yes I have pasted complete code. following are my sysytem configuration: Linux  2.6.18-308.el5 #1 SMP Fri Jan 27 17:17:51 EST 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: The code is fine (did you compiled the test yourself?)

Comment: @DieterLücking Yes I compiled my self, do we need any special library while compiling?

Comment: Look up the code at /usr/include/boost/archive/detail/oserializer.hpp:567 (I have a different version)

Comment: @DieterLücking Thank you for the pointer. The Problem was I was trying to serialize non-const object which is not allowed Now it compiles fine but I got new compilation error if I have map type STL as class data member. Any pointer to this error: "/usr/include/boost/serialization/access.hpp:109: error: 'class std::map<int, int, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, int> > >' has no member named 'serialize'"

Comment: Look up documentation or source code: /usr/include/boost/serialization/map.hpp (just include it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try declaring

```
const gps_position obj(10, 20);
```

As suggested [here](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/newbie-problem-with-Boost-Serialization-td2567024.html);

boost version 1.33 is crazy old, I don't think any of us are going to easily reproduce.